# Java - convert MessagePack timestamp to date

Tags: java, datetime, apache-beam, msgpack

I'm decoding a MessagePack message from an Apache Beam pipeline in a Java project. I'm using Maven to import the MessagePack library as dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.msgpack</groupId>
  <artifactId>msgpack-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.16</version>
</dependency>
```

I can use this to parse the MessagePack message it into key/value pairs in a `Map`, like this:

```
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) 
    {
        try 
        {           
            Map<Value, Value> map = MessagePack.newDefaultUnpacker(c.element().getPayload()).unpackValue().asMapValue().map();
```

The map contains a key/value pair for a MessagePack 'Timestamp' 'extension' type that looks like this, and which represents a date/time (see the 'Note' at the bottom, for an explanation of MessagePack extension types):

```
UTC=(-1,0x5b-161d46)
```

I can get this a 'timestamp' value, by getting the value with the key `UTC`, from the map. I retrieve it as a MessagePack `ExtensionValue` like this:

```
 Value date = map.get(ValueFactory.newString("UTC")).asExtensionValue();
```

`date` is then an object which has 2 properties:

```
`type` = 1
`data` = `0x5b-161d46`
```

How do I convert `data` to a meaningful representation of the date? The 'data' should translate to a 'current' date, sometime around 16th November 2018. It's not as simple as converting the hex value to decimal. Do I need to separately unpack this `data` somehow? I suspect that `5b-161d46` probably needs to be treated as a byte array and then converted somehow.

I can do this to get the `data` part of the extension type as a byte array:

```
byte[] date = map.get(ValueFactory.newString("UTC")).asExtensionValue().getData();
```

which gives me `[91, -22, 29, 70]`

... and I can try to unpack it like this:

```
MessagePack.newDefaultUnpacker(date).unpackValue()
```

... however that just gives me the first byte (`5b`) converted to a `long` i.e. `91`

And if I try any of these I get `org.msgpack.core.MessageTypeCastException`, probably because `unpackValue` just gives me a single `long` number

```
MessagePack.newDefaultUnpacker(date).unpackValue().asIntegerValue();
MessagePack.newDefaultUnpacker(date).unpackValue().asMapValue();
MessagePack.newDefaultUnpacker(date).unpackValue().asRawValue();
```

I've also tried the following:

```
MessageUnpacker unpacker = MessagePack.newDefaultUnpacker(date);
    while(unpacker.hasNext()) {
        MessageFormat f = unpacker.getNextFormat();
            switch(f) {
                case POSFIXINT:
                case NEGFIXINT: {
                    int v = unpacker.unpackInt();
                    break;
                }
             }
    }
```

The values in the array are recognised as either `POSFIXINT` or `NEGFIXINT`, so I can use this to extract decimal integer values for each byte in the array, however that only allows me to extract the elements in the `date` array as integers, and I still don't know how to translate that to a date.

How do I need to interpret/unpack these dates?

---

> **Note** - An extension value is special type of MessagePack value, represented as a tuple where `-1` defines the extension type. `-1` is
>   a reserved extension for a MessagePack `timestamp`, and the remainder
>   gives a hex value (`0x5b-161d46`):
>
> https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#timestamp-extension-type

Comment: I wonder if that means that `61d46` (hex) is the number of seconds since the epoch? That would be 400710 (decimal) seconds or Monday 5th January 1970 15:18:30 UTC. Does that sound right to you? It doesn’t immediately to me, but you should know better. I cannot understand `0x5b-161d46` as one hex value, they don’t have a minus in the middle (at least not where I come from).

Comment: Thanks @Ole V.V. - the date should be a current date (i.e. sometime around our current date). This is what's confusing me. It's like 5b-161d46 should be a hex value that represents the number of seconds, however this format is strange. If I simply ignore the '-' sign (not a good assumption to make), then it gives me 1528175942 in decimal, which is a date of 5th June 2018, which is still wrong, it should be something like 17th November or close to that.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! First, the short version (how to convert a MessagePack timestamp value to a meaningful number in Java):

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

byte[] timestampValues = myTimestampExtensionValue.asExtensionValue().getData();                            
ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(timestampValues);
Long dateValue = wrapped.getLong();
```

---

In my own case, I was receiving the date as a timestamp extension value as part of a key/value pair in a map, like this:

```
UTC=(-1,0x5b-e28-35)
```

This could be in various formats, which was very confusing, e.g.:

```
(-1,0x5b-1b6f-24)
(-1,0x5b-1b7056)
(-1,0x5b-1b58-4)
```

What I discovered is that if I do this:

```
byte[] date = map.get(ValueFactory.newString("UTC")).asExtensionValue().getData();
```

... it always gives me a 32 bit byte array. For my example `UTC=(-1,0x5b-e28-35)`, I get:

```
[91, -14, 40, -53]
```

This also confused me - I couldn't see how this could be an integer. The thing to recognise is that these are *signed bytes*, where negative values are *the value to subtract from the maximum value of that byte, i.e. 255*.

I'm not sure why this happens (probably to conserve memory by requiring less space within each byte). Anyway, the example above translates to the following in decimal:

```
[91, 241, 40, 202]
```

There's an easy way though in Java to convert the original byte array `[91, -14, 40, -53]` to an Integer, by importing `java.nio.ByteBuffer` and using:

```
ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(date);
Integer num = wrapped.getInt();
```

For my example, this gives us `1542596811`, which turns out to be **seconds since the Unix Epoch**. So, if we convert that to milliseconds we now have `1542596811000`, or a date of `Mon 19 November 2018, 14:06:51`. Simple!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. java.time (the modern Java date and time API) accpets *seconds* since the epoch directly, and it’s nicer to avoid doing your own conversion to milliseconds: `Instant.ofEpochSecond(1_542_596_811).atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Melbourne"))`.